# Grep substrings in string/word

Tags: string, unix, grep, substring

Is there a way on `grep` or any other unix tool to search for a sequence of substrings in a string?

To clarify:

```
$ grep "substring1.*subrstring2"
substring1_mySubstring2   # OK substrings forming a single string 
substring1 substring2     # WRONG substrings are separated`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell `grep` to look for `substring1` + some characters + `substring2`:

```
grep -iE 'substring1\w+substring2' file
```

Note the usage of `-i` to ignore case and `-E` for an extended regex coverage (the same without `-E` could be done with `\w\+` instead).

#### Test

```
$ cat a
substring1_mySubstring2
substring1 substring2
substring1_and_other_things12345substring2 blabla
```

Let's see how this matches just when there is no spaces in between:

```
$ grep -iE 'substring1\w+substring2' a
substring1_mySubstring2
substring1_and_other_things12345substring2 blabla
```